# Rephrased Inquiry: Outputting Digits of Number in Correct Order Using Loops and Modulus

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, modulus

The question I posted before was worded poorly and I apologize. Here is what I really wanted: I have to create a DigitsDisplay application that prompts the user for a non-negative integer and then displays each digit on a separate line. The digits should be listed so the ones' digit is on the bottom. I don't know how big the number is going to be.

Example:
12456

1

2

4

5

6

Does anyone know how to do this with loops and modulus? No fancy stuff just a simple while statement.
This is what I have so far:

```
int digit;
        System.out.print("Enter a #: ");
        digit = console.nextInt();

        int count = 0;

        while (digit != 0) {
            count += 1;
            digit = digit % 10;
            System.out.println(digit);
        }
```

But it's not working and I don't know how to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store remainder in a int variable and change your digit in each iteration using `/`.
you can push remainder in each iteration in a `stack` and in last,you can pop all the items.

```
    int remainder=0;
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

    while (digit != 0) {
                count += 1;
                remainder= digit % 10;
                digit=digit/10;
                stack.push(remainder);

            }

   while(!stack.isEmpty())
      System.out.println(stack.pop());
```

If you dont wanna use Stack, you can achieve it using recursion too.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String a1[]) {
        int digit = 1234;
        printData(digit);

    }

    public static void printData(int number) {
        if (number == 0)
            return;
        int remainder = number % 10;
        number = number / 10;
        printData(number);
        System.out.println(remainder);

    }

}
```